# load images url via String kotlin

Tags: kotlin

l am new in kotlin and I have an API which returns JSON and his working fine when he return with data . I would like to load an logo from a URL in list view .but the problem is the images is not showing when lunching app , only the data json text show in list view . the way which l want to load logo url via String code . example
 `"https://www.xxxx.com/static/images/data/operators/"+code+"_logo0.png"`

l want get logo for airlines using code of airlines example like IAW . and the code of the airlines he is already in my data json url .

the way l am try to get logo

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

    val view : View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false)


    val code = view.findViewById(R.id.code_id) as AppCompatTextView
    val LogoAriline = view.findViewById(R.id.logo_image) as ImageView

    code.text = list[position].logo
    Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse("https://www.xxxx.com/static/images/data/operators/"+code+"_logo0.png")).into(LogoAriline)



    return view as View
}
}
```

data class

```
package com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports

data class FlightShdu (val Callsign : String, val Airline : String , val logo : String)
```

l just want use the code of the airline inside the url to show in list view depend on data json url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Uri.parse("https://www.xxxx.com/static/images/data/operators/"+code+"_logo0.png")` with `"https://www.xxxx.com/static/images/data/operators/"+code.text.toString()+"_logo0.png"`

and replace `get()` with `with(context)`

Comment: when l use .Picasso.with(context) in kotlin l got unresolved reference with

Comment: Regardless of that you dont need to `Uri.parse(..)` the url, and remember to use `code.text.toString()` instead of just `code`

Comment: l edited some code with your code and his working fine       `Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse("https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/static/images/data/operators/"+code.text.toString()+"_logo0.png")).into(LogoAriline)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `get()` and change `code` to `code.text`:

```
Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse("https://www.xxxx.com/static/images/data/operators/"+code.text+"_logo0.png")).into(LogoAriline)
```

Comment: when l use .Picasso.with(context) in kotlin l got unresolved reference with

Comment: On what? Inside `getView()` I see that you use `context` so it is not unresolved. So where is the `unresolved reference`?